# Values in variables not displaying on Serial monitor

Tags: floating-point, stm32, gyroscope, stm32cubeide, mpu6050

Trying to read mpu 6050 accelerometer,gyroscope values on serial monitor through uart on a stm32g431cbt6 board. The string gets printed except for the values which remain at zero. [Serial Monitor Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Z2H.png). Is it a problem with the implementation of HAL_UART_Transmit_IT or is it something related to the data type?

```
char AccelX[50];
char AccelY[50];
char AccelZ[50];
char GyroX[50];
char GyroY[50];
char GyroZ[50];
char data[200];

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
#define SMPLRT_DIV_REG 0x19
#define GYRO_CONFIG_REG 0x1B
#define ACCEL_CONFIG_REG 0x1C
#define ACCEL_XOUT_H_REG 0x3B
#define TEMP_OUT_H_REG 0x41
#define GYRO_XOUT_H_REG 0x43
#define PWR_MGMT_1_REG 0x6B
#define WHO_AM_I_REG 0x75


int16_t Accel_X_RAW = 0;
int16_t Accel_Y_RAW = 0;
int16_t Accel_Z_RAW = 0;

int16_t Gyro_X_RAW = 0;
int16_t Gyro_Y_RAW = 0;
int16_t Gyro_Z_RAW = 0;

float Ax, Ay, Az, Gx, Gy, Gz, ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;

const double Accel_Z_corrector = 14418.0;

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
   // do nothing here
}

void MPU6050_Init (void)
{
    uint8_t check;
    uint8_t Data;

    // check device ID WHO_AM_I

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read (&hi2c1, (0b1101000 <<1) + 0,WHO_AM_I_REG,1, &check, 1, 100);

    if (check == 104)  // 0x68 will be returned by the sensor if everything goes well
    {
        // power management register 0X6B we should write all 0's to wake the sensor up
        Data = 0;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (0b1101000 <<1) + 0, PWR_MGMT_1_REG, 1,&Data, 1, 100);

        // Set DATA RATE of 1KHz by writing SMPLRT_DIV register
        Data = 0x07;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (0b1101000 <<1) + 0, SMPLRT_DIV_REG, 1, &Data, 1, 100);

        // Set accelerometer configuration in ACCEL_CONFIG Register
        // XA_ST=0,YA_ST=0,ZA_ST=0, FS_SEL=0 -> � 2g
        Data = 0x00;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (0b1101000 <<1) + 0, ACCEL_CONFIG_REG, 1, &Data, 1, 100);

        // Set Gyroscopic configuration in GYRO_CONFIG Register
        // XG_ST=0,YG_ST=0,ZG_ST=0, FS_SEL=0 -> � 250 �/s
        Data = 0x00;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (0b1101000 <<1) + 0, GYRO_CONFIG_REG, 1, &Data, 1, 100);
    }

}


void MPU6050_Read_Accel (void)
{
    uint8_t Rec_Data[6];

    // Read 6 BYTES of data starting from ACCEL_XOUT_H register

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read (&hi2c1, (0b1101000 <<1) + 0, ACCEL_XOUT_H_REG, 1, Rec_Data, 6, 100);

    Accel_X_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[0] << 8 | Rec_Data [1]);
    Accel_Y_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[2] << 8 | Rec_Data [3]);
    Accel_Z_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[4] << 8 | Rec_Data [5]);

    /*** convert the RAW values into acceleration in 'g'
         we have to divide according to the Full scale value set in FS_SEL
         FS_SEL = 0. So dividing by 16384.0
                       ****/

    Ax = Accel_X_RAW/16384.0;
    Ay = Accel_Y_RAW/16384.0;
    Az = Accel_Z_RAW/Accel_Z_corrector;



}


void MPU6050_Read_Gyro (void)
{
    uint8_t Rec_Data[6];

    // Read 6 BYTES of data starting from GYRO_XOUT_H register

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read (&hi2c1, (0b1101000 <<1) + 0, GYRO_XOUT_H_REG, 1, Rec_Data, 6, 100);

    Gyro_X_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[0] << 8 | Rec_Data [1]);
    Gyro_Y_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[2] << 8 | Rec_Data [3]);
    Gyro_Z_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[4] << 8 | Rec_Data [5]);

    /*** convert the RAW values into dps (�/s)
                       ****/

    Gx = Gyro_X_RAW/131.0;
    Gy = Gyro_Y_RAW/131.0;
    Gz = Gyro_Z_RAW/131.0;

}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  MPU6050_Init();


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      MPU6050_Read_Accel();
      MPU6050_Read_Gyro();


          sprintf(AccelX, "Accelerometer X: %.2f g\r\n",ax);
          sprintf(AccelY, "Accelerometer Y: %.2f g\r\n",ay);
          sprintf(AccelZ, "Accelerometer Z: %.2f g\r\n",az);

          sprintf(GyroX, "Gyroscope X: %.2f dps\r\n", gx);
          sprintf(GyroY, "Gyroscope Y: %.2f dps\r\n", gy);
          sprintf(GyroZ, "Gyroscope Z: %.2f dps\r\n", gz);



          strcpy(data,AccelX);
          strcat(data,AccelY);
          strcat(data,AccelZ);
          strcat(data,GyroX);
          strcat(data,GyroY);
          strcat(data,GyroZ);

          HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)data, strlen(data));




          HAL_Delay(1000); // Delay 1 second
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `printf` implementation does not support float numbers. You need to enable it in the cubeIDE

[image]

Comment: I already did that.